# macOS will not remember AirPrint password

Tags: mojave, password, keychain, printing, airprint

[macOS 10.14.5]

I have an HP OfficeJet Pro 8710, all the latest firmware updates as of today, and have changed the default AirPrint username/password. I can successfully print. However, even though I check the **Remember this password in my keychain** option, I have to re-enter the Name/Password each time. How can I fix this?
[image: AirPrint dialog]

Comment: Have you verified the authentication info is actually saved in your keychain? If you find an entry for the printer, delete it and try re-authenticating to see if it 'sticks'.

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks for the suggestion. It was present in Keychain; I deleted it and re-created it, but still the same results. I even changed Access Control to 'Allow all applications' but that didn't help either.